# как поменять голос на мужской использую модули speech_recognition pyttsx3

Tags: python, pyttsx3

я пишу голосового помощника и мне бы хотелось чтобы голос был мужской я думаю что дело в voices[0].id но меняя его на 1 у меня просто перестает работать озвучивалка текста

```
def speak(text):
    engine.setProperty('rate', 200)
    engine.setProperty('volume', 'ru')
    voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
    engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)  #changing index, changes voices. o for male
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()


# запуск
while True:
    response = recognize_speech()

    if response:
        reply = classify_response(response)
        speak(reply)
        time.sleep(1)
```